# The sum of each every below of their numbers on column "AF". Added up by each others gradually line by line pointing upwards by formula in G.sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I want to **SUM** every numbers on column "**AF**" row by row like gradually. Adding their number to each other is like a ladder which is added up gradually line by line pointing upwards. And with multiple criterias based on colums "**K**" and "**O**" and doing this all by formula. Can we do this some stuffs like this ?

I was trying with my attemp and it seems failed it doesn't work at all. And please see my formula code down below here :
`=FILTER(IF($AF$3:$AF="";"";IF(IFERROR(MATCH($O$3:$O;$O:$O;0);0)=ROW($O$3:$O);SUMIF($O$3:$O;$O$3:$O;$AF$3:$AF)+SUMIF($O$3:$O;$O$3:$O;$AE$3:$AE);""));$O$3:$O<>"0")`

And I attached the picture to explain more and than so you'll be understand what I mean is. And with the "**expect output**" in it hope can make this question more be clearly. Thanks in advance!

[My sample spreadsheet feel free to edit](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bu4RY0NAJQTg9j_ljFb94lecc1Tdf55HTAAD7UcUUHw/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 yes player0 ...  it does !  See the update of question I was put the link too !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formula like this. I don't get if you need to check if K is "CHECKOUT", if you don't delete that conditional:

```
=byrow(AF3:AF;lambda(each;if(each="";"";sumifs(INDIRECT("AF"&row(each)&":AF");Indirect("O"&row(each)&":O");Indirect("O"&row(each));Indirect("K"&row(each)&":K");"CHECKOUT"))))
```

It's in AK in your spreadsheet!

Comment: Hi, @Martin how if I'm going to get the result **MINUS** from each of them (turns into reverse side) ?

Comment: Hello! I'm glad it worked! You mean like a running count? Summing the numbers up to down until each row??

Comment: I mean like not use a "**SUM**" function but how to about change that to the "**MINUS**" function instead of SUM for their each row pointing to upwards. I thought I was trying to change that into "**MINIFS**" but I was _**wrong**_ because it's not for a MINUS function but in other hand it's like for another function like minimum of number in dataset. What I want is to get **SUBTRACTION** every each row of them SUBTRACT from the number every below of each of them.

Comment: Could you upload an example? Maybe create a new question (and put here the link for reference) to see your desired result

Comment: Yes .. I have in another question here @Martin. Please see to here: [ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74525833/the-subtraction-from-the-number-of-each-below-of-row-on-column-af-get-minus-eac).