# The subtraction from the number of each below of row on column AF. Get minus each others gradually row by row pointing upwards by formula in G.sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

`=byrow(AF3:AF;lambda(each;if(each="";"";SUMIFS(INDIRECT("AF"&row(each)&":AF");Indirect("O"&row(each)&":O");Indirect("O"&row(each));Indirect("K"&row(each)&":K");"CHECKOUT"))))`

***the formulas by @Martin!***

From the above of the formulas by @Martin I try to modify a litle bit to ajustment to my kinda of my case I thought by trying to change the "**SUMIFS**" into "**MINIFS**" will comes out as I expected but well it's not. It's not working at all even close as I imagine it before. I was wrong because it's not for a *MINUS* function but in other hand it's like for another function to get a *MINIMUM* of number in a dataset.

What I want is to get a ***SUBTRACTION*** every each row of them *SUBTRACT* from the number of every below of each of them ***with the two conditions :***
**first:* based on the **NAME** on column "**O**".
**second:* based on the criteria I desired and should be a certain value like **CHECKOUT** on column "**K**".

And I attached the link to explain more and than so you'll be understand what I mean is. And with the "expect output" in it hope can make this question more be clearly. Thanks in advance!

[Please, feel free to edit My Example Quest of Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bu4RY0NAJQTg9j_ljFb94lecc1Tdf55HTAAD7UcUUHw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't there anyway for you of differentiating that first values to be substracted from? (Or maybe eventually there would be more). For example putting "CHECKIN" to those values and "CHECKOUT" for all the ones that will diminish it. In that case you could modify that original formula and sum all the CHECKINs and substract from it all the CHECKOUTS

I've put it in a new tab of your spreadsheet, let me know if this could work for you:

```
=byrow(AF3:AF;lambda(each;if(each="";"";IF(OR(INDIRECT("K"&row(each))="CHECKIN";INDIRECT("K"&row(each))="CHECKOUT");sumifs(INDIRECT("AF"&row(each)&":AF");Indirect("O"&row(each)&":O");Indirect("O"&row(each));Indirect("K"&row(each)&":K");"CHECKIN")-sumifs(INDIRECT("AF"&row(each)&":AF");Indirect("O"&row(each)&":O");Indirect("O"&row(each));Indirect("K"&row(each)&":K");"CHECKOUT");""))))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah ..  so yeah ..  I got it now!  so there's no way to not put a decision on first as a main value to subtracting that from all of subtraction yeah.  Wow ..  It's Amazing. Out of my imagined it means that it so incredible @Martin because I was almost depressed about that hehe ...  but luckly here with you. You save me twice. Thank you so much @Martin!

Comment: There are ways, but it'd get more confusing and less flexible the formula. Sometimes you have to deal with some outcome of a 3rd party software and you can't negotiate ways of inputting data, but if there is the possibility you can simplify it like this ;)

Comment: Yeah it's okey @Martin the important like what I want is it was get the resulting as an output as I expected sucha for a long time ago ...  It was since sucha along along time ago I've been get strugling with these so far away before until the finnally then I've got decision to this to think to create the question here then here I am finnaly got the answer from you! Yeah ... Thanks once again Martin!

Comment: Hey @Martin please see my new question, martin! I post a new one which is still has to get realeted to this question and I still need your help..  hehe   ^_^